# Delivering DM&E stems

Tags: stems, mixing, limiting

How are your sessions built so that when the client receives final stems, the comped level doesn't exceed a given threshold?  The way I set up my sessions is audio tracks feed aux inputs (D, M & E stems) which feed a comp input. Each of these inputs then feed audio tracks which I record the stems onto.  I can put a limiter on the comp input so that when it records to a track it doesn't exceed a given threshold, but what happens if the client wants JUST D, M & E stems?  How can I control the overall level when these tracks are summed?

*The highlighted tracks are my Aux Inputs.

[image]

Is there a better way to organize my session?  I am going to start mixing promos that will be mixed for web, possibly for broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

Can't quite see your session there, the pic is a bit too small to read the text.

Anyway, I have my outputs split into the following stems for all our international shows...

Mix
M&E
Music
FX
Dialogue

I'll use the Mix track to explain but they're all identical.

Mix Stem (Aux Track) (L2 limiter set at -10)

output to...

Mix Master (Master Track) (POWr dither for layback to tape)
Mix Print (Audio Track)

To create all my stems I simply record all the Print tracks, which will be identical to what's on tape. All the routing is done within ProTools and is part of my main mix template so I never need to re-route anything or think how it's going to work.

Comment: @ian - do the specs you're working with regularly ask for mix minuses?  I've figured out a quick/painless way to create these in Nuendo, but I'm still trying to figure out how to make things easier/more efficient in PT.  Would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: All the shows I do for the international markets have it written into the contract as it'll be a co-production.
Even the cookery shows I do for a particular Irish company have asked for them which is odd considering all you then get it the occasional music and close up sizzle and nothing else.

The routing above is how I do it, pretty simple once you see it in action.